# sudo fails when disk is full

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I have an ubuntu 16.04 system that has filled the root partition with logs (written by root so reserved space did not save us).

The problem is that attempts to do anything via sudo fail at authentication.  I am guessing that this is caused by failure to write some file or other.

I don't have any files that I can delete without sudo.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take the system offline, correct the problem, check the filesystem that was filled, then reboot back into native.

Comment: The issue is that, being an ubuntu system, there is no root login.  By default you are expected to use sudo.  If you can't use sudo you appear to be screwed.

Comment: Give root a password. Ubuntu doesn't do so during its installer, but setting one on allows you to log in as root during emergencies. For now, just boot a different live system such as the Ubuntu installer disk and fix things from there.

Comment: Thanks Small Loan, OK so  I need to reboot into something else to fix it. I was trying to avoid that for reasons I won't bore your with.  I will probably end up rebuilding it with a separate partition for /var *and* set a root password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot in recovery mode. You can select it at the GRUB bootloader screen (if you don't see it during boot, keep pressing F8 until it appears).

Recovery mode will give you a root shell by default. Mount your filesystems and remove the files.

Reboot in normal mode.